# Are there any known plans for Paizo to move Pathfinder to D&D 5e?

Tags: dnd-5e, pathfinder-1e, publishing

Are there any concrete documents or plans that show Paizo (the Pathfinder publishers) are planning to move to D&D 5e?

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic for reasons covered in [this meta](http://meta.rpg.stackexchange.com/q/1227/15469).

Comment: I'm voting to reopen because I don't think a policy of closing a question like this exists or is all that necessary or sensible. I don't think this is even the category of question covered in that meta: we *do* have current answers, as have been provided: "no, and it's misunderstanding the context to expect such a move". Leave it open: if it doesn't seem so we can say so (as we've done); if some update arrives on the subject such that the answer changes, we might as well have this question open to receive that update.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

**No. Not at the time of this answer.**

Paizo and WotC are not the same company. Back when D&D 4th edition was released, [Paizo chose to stop supporting D&D, instead releasing their system as a standalone OGL modified from the 3.5e rules](https://www.wired.com/2008/03/no-dd-4e-for-pa/). In effect, Pathfinder is its own independent game which happens to have its roots in an older edition of another game. Since there was no jump to 4th edition, it is unreasonable to expect a jump to 5th, especially as no such commentary has come out of the publishers, unlike what happened when 4th was released.

Comment: Not to mention, Paizo have also announced they are releasing Starfinder, also based on D&D 3.5.